# Did the `each` method change its behavior?

Tags: ruby

A Ruby exercise about multidimensional array said that two instances of `each` method are necessary to access the inner elements of a multidimensional array. The following:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
x.each do |a|
  a.each do |b|
    puts b
  end
end
```

should return:

```
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

However, it's not necessary to use two `each` methods. If I just do

```
x.each { |a| puts a }
```

I get the same result. It seems a single instance of `each` already goes to the inner level of multidimensional arrays.

In that case, how would I access the first level? In other words, how would I get the following?

```
# [1,2]
# [3,4]
# [5,6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different print functions in Ruby. Let's try them in the Ruby prompt:

```
> puts [1,2]
1
2
=> nil

> p [1,2]
[1, 2]
=> [1, 2]

> print [1,2]
[1, 2]=> nil
```

In case you aren't familiar with `irb`, the expression following the fat arrow `=>` is the return value of the statement.

Comment: Oh, ok! So it's not about the behaviour of `each` but `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if you do just

```
puts x
```

you'll get exactly the same result. This is because `puts` treats arrays in a special manner. It enumerates all elements and calls `puts` on them individually. (this is recursive, as you might imagine).

This will get roughly the output you want:

```
x.each {|a| p a}
```

or

```
x.each {|a| puts a.inspect }
```

Output

```
# >> [1, 2]
# >> [3, 4]
# >> [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.each { |a| puts a }
```

This will call puts on each element of the x array.

It is the same as doing :

```
puts [1,2]
puts [3,4]
puts [5,6]
```

puts on an array will format it like you saw.